# how to approach this in MySql query?

Tags: mysql, criteria

I want to select the data as per condition:I have a table with physician_key and corresponding quality score for a given month. I want to select count of distinct physicians with quality score 1,2.
For a month, there could be more entries for a physician_key and accordingly the quality assigned(on scale 1-7). I want to select only the count of those physicians which have quality (1,2) and if the same physician has quality >2 in given month, I don't want to count that physician.I want the information by product and month

Comment: Welcome to SO. You'll get better help if you do a couple of things: First, change your question title to something descriptive. (Pretty much everything on SO boils down to "How can this be done?") Secondly, this question is difficult to answer without a description of your table schema.

Answer (score 1):

I created an example table, since you didn't provide one:

```
mysql> select * from sales_mkt_rep_qual;
+-------------------+---------+-------+-------------------+
| GEO_PHYSICIAN_KEY | product | month | SALES_REP_QUALITY |
+-------------------+---------+-------+-------------------+
|                 1 | a       |     8 |                 1 |
|                 1 | a       |     8 |                 2 |
|                 1 | a       |     8 |                 3 |
|                 2 | b       |     8 |                 2 |
|                 2 | b       |     8 |                 1 |
|                 2 | b       |     9 |                 2 |
|                 1 | a       |     9 |                 2 |
|                 2 | b       |     9 |                 3 |
|                 3 | a       |     9 |                 2 |
+-------------------+---------+-------+-------------------+
```

The query from your comment indeed gives an error:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT GEO_PHYSICIAN_KEY) AS encount_1to2,
       product,MONTH 
FROM   sales_mkt_rep_qual 
WHERE MAX(SALES_REP_QUALITY) = 2 ;

ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
```

If you change that to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT geo_physician_key AS encount_1to2, product, month 
FROM sales_mkt_rep_qual 
WHERE (geo_physician_key,month,product) 
   NOT IN (
      SELECT geo_physician_key, month, product 
      FROM sales_mkt_rep_qual 
      WHERE sales_rep_quality >2  );
```

you see the detailed result:

```
+--------------+---------+-------+
| encount_1to2 | product | month |
+--------------+---------+-------+
|            2 | b       |     8 |
|            1 | a       |     9 |
|            3 | a       |     9 |
+--------------+---------+-------+
```

No, you can introduce the counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct geo_physician_key ) AS no_of_physicians,product, month 
FROM sales_mkt_rep_qual 
WHERE (geo_physician_key,month,product) 
      NOT IN (
         SELECT geo_physician_key, month, product 
         FROM sales_mkt_rep_qual WHERE sales_rep_quality >2  ) 
GROUP BY month, product;

+------------------+---------+-------+
| no_of_physicians | product | month |
+------------------+---------+-------+
|                1 | b       |     8 |
|                2 | a       |     9 |
+------------------+---------+-------+
```

If that still isn't what you are looking for, give more specific table structure and data example.

Comment: Actually I want the data to be like 

+--------------+---------+-------+ | encount_1to2 | product | MONTH | +--------------+---------+-------+ | 2 | b | 8 | +--------------+---------+-------+

and for the criteria SALES_REP_QUALITY <= 2, isn't there a possibility that while selecting the distinct geo physician key, it might select out of first 2 considering it matches the criteria? Thats the reason I have used Thanix approach of max function with group by product and month, so that the aggregate function is applied on every product within a month

Comment: And actually, asking the question again under a different username is bad form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT count(DISTINCT physician_key)
    FROM my_table
   WHERE month = desired_month
     AND max(quality) = 2
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: it will select the count even if the same physician has one occurrence of quality score 1 or 2, howevere he may have high score on another day and if thats the case I dont' want to select him

Comment: I've edited the `SELECT` so that it now only considers physicians that have achieved at most 2.

Comment: I am trying this and its not working                                select count(distinct GEO_PHYSICIAN_KEY) as encount_1to2,product,MONTH from sales_mkt_rep_qual 
  where max(SALES_REP_QUALITY) = 2 group by product,MONTH

Answer (score 0):

Actually I want the data to be like the output below:

```
+--------------+---------+-------+
| encount_1to2 | product | MONTH |
+--------------+---------+-------+
|            2 | b       |     8 |
+--------------+---------+-------+
```

and for the criteria SALES_REP_QUALITY <= 2, isn't there a possibility that while selecting the distinct geo physician key, it might select out of first 2 considering it matches the criteria? Thats the reason I have used Thanix approach of max function with group  by product and month, so that the aggregate function is applied on every product within a month